# VB.NET Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: datagridview, vb.net-2010

I have been using the following code to changes the cell value color in a datagridview without any problem until I transfer it to a new project, and connecting the project to a different server.  and it is now throwing a "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error..  What am I missing??

It work from GridViewTextBoxColumn1, until it move down to GridViewTextBoxColumn2 and the debugger start throwing error like.  Value cannot be converted to type Datetime, then Object reference not set etc..  But I check everywhere and everything seems to be in place, and don't understand how it ended up with a datetime..

```
 Private Sub TableGrid_CellFormatting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles TableGrid.CellFormatting

    For i As Integer = Nothing To Me.TableGrid.Rows.Count - 1
        If Me.TableGrid.Rows(i).Cells("GridViewTextBoxColumn1").Value <= 0 Then
            Me.TableGrid.Rows(i).Cells("GridViewTextBoxColumn1").Style.ForeColor = Color.Red
        End If
    Next
    For j As Integer = Nothing To Me.TableGrid.Rows.Count - 1
        If Me.TableGrid.Rows(j).Cells("GridViewTextBoxColumn2").Value.ToString = "S" Then
            Me.TableGrid.Rows(j).Cells("GridViewTextBoxColumn2").Style.ForeColor = Color.Blue
        End If
    Next

    For k As Integer = Nothing To Me.TableGrid.Rows.Count - 1
        If Me.TableGrid.Rows(k).Cells("GridViewTextBoxColumn3").Value.ToString = "Z" Then
            Me.TableGrid.Rows(k).Cells("GridViewTextBoxColumn3").Style.ForeColor = Color.Blue
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution that work to my own question.. But I believe there should be better answer.

The codes in my first question did not test for null values that exist in some cells.  Hence, the error..

```
For i As Integer = 0 To Me.TableGrid.Rows.Count - 1
If Not Me.TableGrid.Rows(i).Cells("DataGridViewTextBoxColumn1").Value Is DBNull.Value Then
If Me.TableGrid.Rows(i).Cells("DataGridViewTextBoxColumn1").Value = "Z" Then
Me.TableGrid.Rows(i).Cells("DataGridViewTextBoxColumn1").Style.ForeColor = Color.Blue
End If
End If

        If Not Me.TableGrid.Rows(i).Cells("DataGridViewTextBoxColumn2").Value Is DBNull.Value Then
            If Me.TableGrid.Rows(i).Cells("DataGridViewTextBoxColumn2").Value <0 Then
                Me.TableGrid.Rows(i).Cells("DataGridViewTextBoxColumn2").Style.ForeColor = Color.Red
            End If
        End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually this error occurs when trying to reference an object that has not had anything assigned to it yet so make sure your datagrid cells actually have values in them.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the tips.  The below code works on cells with null values and only highlight those with values.

Answer (score 0):

Try "Dim yourobject As New Yourtype", since the "New" is usually needed when this exception is thrown,